# SQL Server 2008 data types: which ones should i use?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, types

I am trying to figure out which data types I should use for my tables. Does someone have a very good, simple, tutorial on SQL Server 2008 datatypes (has to be practical!) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3788256/Data-Types-in-SQL-Server-2008.htm
http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feature/SQL-Server-2008-data-types-Datetime-string-user-defined-and-more 
The first link is more practical. As far as I know, SQL Server 2005 and 2008 almost have the same data types. (except new DateTime data type).

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a nice post](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/10things/?p=355).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way of choosing the type is self knowledge about project mixed with the knowledge of available types that why i advise You to get familiar with [Data types in MS-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848733.aspx) and [generally with MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx)